# Not able to make call using Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make a call using intent, If i try to run this code from linux eclipse its working fine, but on windows eclipse its not working. Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"1234567890"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is the errors???

Comment: Why you need to set a flag in phone call, remove that, it will work

Comment: I am using it inside my adapter, without using Flag it gives error

Comment: so write a method to make phone call with out flag and call that from your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Use this for Windows. It may Help you

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
  + Uri.encode("Your Number here")));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is makes difference? OP said **If i try to run this code from linux eclipse its working fine, but on windows eclipse its not working**.  Not in Device

Answer (score 1):

Try this for calling

```
      Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "9876543210"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

And add this permission in Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```